Android 14: Notification with PendingIntent Not Reappearing After Second Dismissal (Phone Locked)
I’m experiencing an issue with notifications in Android 14. I’ve created a notification with a PendingIntent that launches my app, and it works fine initially. However, when I dismiss the notification twice while my phone is locked, the notification doesn’t reappear, even though I expect it to be triggered again.
I have added the android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission in the manifest.
I’m using PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE and PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT when creating the PendingIntent.
The notification is correctly tied to a notification channel.
Is there any known behavior change in Android 14 regarding notification handling with the phone locked, or am I missing something in my setup?
